# "der Person des Monarchen als höchster staatlichen Instanz unterstellt" or "der Person des Monarchen als höchster staatlicher Instanz unterstellt"?

Tags: dative, genitive, declension, attribute

From Wikipedia [Königlich Preußen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6niglich_Preu%C3%9Fen):

> Königlich Preußen war ein autonomer, vom Deutschordensstaat abgefallener Ständestaat mit eigenem Landtag, der aus dem von den Ständen (Städte und Adel) im Ordensstaat gebildeten Preußischen Bund hervorgegangen war und der sich freiwillig der Person des polnischen Monarchen als höchster staatlichen Instanz unterstellt hatte.

Either "der Person des polnischen Monarchen" can be cut down to "dem polnischen Monarchen" or "der Person", both dative. You could then as well say "der Person als der höchsten staatlichen Instanz" so that both are dative ("der Person als wem oder was?").

Or you tell more about the "Monarch", which is genitive:

"des polnischen Monarchen, der höchsten staatlichen Instanz", but the shortcut of that would be "der Person des Monarchen als höchster staatlicher Instanz" or "der Person des Monarchen, höchster staatlicher Instanz".

Could it still somehow be right to say "der Person des Monarchen als höchster staatlichen Instanz unterstellt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's probably a typo or an editing error. You already explained it very well.

Comment: Wäre es vielleicht richtig bei Verwendung eines Kommas, also "als höchster, staatlicher Instanz"?

Comment: @userunknown du hast ja nicht nur ein Komma gesetzt, sondern auch das n durch ein r ersetzt. Dann stimmt es natürlich, mit oder ohne Komma.

Comment: Ach so, ja, jetzt sehe ich.